# Getting date and time of system startup in Linux

Tags: linux, uptime

I know that `uptime` prints the time a machine has been up and running, but is there an easier (reliable) way to get the date of the start up than counting down from this output?

I tried looking around `/proc`, but didn't find anything of relevance. There's also a line like this on my `dmesg`:

```
[    0.673492] rtc_cmos rtc_cmos: setting system clock to 2011-03-14 14:26:52 UTC (1300112812)
```

But I'm wondering if this method is distribution and kernel version agnostic?

Comment: What's `unreliable or hard` about `uptime`?

Comment: @Bobby: Nothing about the command or its function per se, but as said I want to get the date and time of last system boot, not how long it's been up since. `uptime` returns a string like "up 13 days, 21:01", and you'd need to count it from that.

Comment: It's trivial to count back from the uptime value. If you want *reliable*, you want `/proc/uptime`.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I found some commands [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-last-reboot-time-and-date-find-out.html).  Try `who -b` or `last reboot | head -1`.
`who` gives numeric dates, while `last reboot` returns abbreviated day / month names.

Comment: how about if we only want the date and nothing else?

Comment: `who -b | cut -d' ' -f13` returns date only (-f14 returns time)

Comment: Warning: `last reboot` did not give me the correct date ! `who -b` did.

Comment: `last reboot` gave me an incorrect date too, wtmp seemed to have been rotated first day of the month

Answer (score 27):

This queries the uptime from the kernel and displays it in the local timezone:

```
date -d "`cut -f1 -d. /proc/uptime` seconds ago"
```

Be careful about other options. The `last` command will stop working as soon as `wtmp` has been rotated. The `who` command depends on the availability and integrity of `utmp`. And `/proc/1` might have the current date instead of the boot time date, and could even be unavailable on a hardened system. **Edit**: `dmesg` only has a fixed-length back buffer, so it is unrealiable, too. The kernel logs may be in `/var/log` but most distributions only keep 8 weeks of them.

Comment: Interestingly, this disagrees with `who -b` by a minute or two on my 210-days-uptime system. Looks like `who -b` reports a time stamp, while this counting is somehow affected by clock drifts, even if these are periodically corrected by a running `ntpd`.

Comment: After reviewing all the alternate answers, settled on: **`date -d "\`cut -f1 -d. /proc/uptime\` seconds ago" -u`** (which has time/date in UTC)

Comment: Phenomenal answer. If the kernel don't know, nobody knows- it's the Source of Truth for the system. The seconds make it easy to perform time calculations (I stumbled on this because I want to know "Which of my hosts didn't reboot within the last day [86,400 seconds]?")

Comment: I have a machine with a faulty RTC (realtime clock), where the clock is only correctly set after boot.


`who -b` reports the time with the faulty time.


`/proc/uptime` by definition of the calculation will report the actual boot time.

Answer (score 24):

I stumbled on this question while looking for a way to get a consistent, parseable *boot time*, as opposed to *time since boot* which changes on every call.

It appears that `uptime -s` will do the trick on most linux systems.

Comment: `uptime -s` outputs e.g. `2017-08-09 01:23:45`. This is best, by being simplest. This command is included in the package "procps".

Comment: The `uptime` in CentOS 6 (`procps version 3.2.8`) does not seem to support this, sadly.

Comment: `uptime -s` does not always return constant results: https://superuser.com/q/1247713/71144

Comment: Note that this is always in **localtime**, but it does not actually print the timezone/offset. So, if you're looking to pull this from machines programmatically, it's not ideal, as you may need to separately determine their timezone, depending on your use case. So, I'd suggest some of the other answers.

Answer (score 12):

I found the `btime` line in `/proc/stat` when poking around a bit

```
cat /proc/stat | grep btime | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

and after a quick search, I found this page: [/proc/stat explained](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/System/procstat.htm), which outlines the "Various pieces of information about kernel activity that are available in the
`/proc/stat` file."

> The "btime" line gives the time at which the system booted, in seconds since
>   the Unix epoch.

Comment: Seems a lot easier to write `awk '/btime/{print $2}' /proc/stat`

Comment: @WilliamPursell easiest is always what you already know. I am no awk wizard. :P

Comment: Good point. However, you used cat gratuitously. Just grep from the file.

Comment: @MikeS correct – however, I still stand by my original command chain as a clear representation of where the information is found, even 7 years after my answer.

Answer (score 9):

- **good**: `uptime -s`, `who -b` or parsing `/proc/uptime`
- **bad**: `ls -ld /proc/1` and variants.

Don't use ls -ld /proc/1 for this purpose. *It's sometimes updated* after s2disk or s2ram.

In my case, `who -b` said:

system boot  May  2 09:51

While `ls -ld /proc/1`:

dr-xr-xr-x 7 root root 0 May  3 13:09 /proc/1

`ls -ld` for `/proc` or `/sys` seem to persist after resuming, but it's implementation dependent, and may change in future, so don't use such methods. **And** if your *system clock is in localtime, not UTC*, they have negative offset.

(I don't have the privilege to comment to answers yet, so opened a new answer. Sorry.)

EDIT: `uptime -s` was first answered [in this answer](https://superuser.com/a/834728/131062) by [mikegreiling](https://superuser.com/users/176767/mikegreiling)

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to look to see when /sbin/init started (that's always the first process to be started after the kernel loads):

```
# ls -ld /proc/1
dr-xr-xr-x 7 root root 0 2011-03-27 23:54 /proc/1
```

So I can see that my machine booted up at 6 minutes to midnight on the 27th of March 2011.

If you want to use it in scripting you can use the `stat` command instead:

```
# stat --printf='%Y' /proc/1
1301266491
```

The `%Y` specifies the time since the directory was last changed (process creation time) in seconds since the epoch (1/1/70) and is a standard unix timestamp.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work: the mtime on those folders can change for other reasons (I have a system here that has a 5 day uptime and the mtime of /proc/1 is 25 minutes ago)

Comment: It's **not reliable**, as explained in [my answer](http://superuser.com/a/422747/131062)

Answer (score 2):

This seems robust and will give it to you in UTC and ISO8601 format.  (Remove the last two options to disable either, respectively):

```
date -d "`cut -f1 -d. /proc/uptime` seconds ago" -u -Iseconds
```

Answer (score 1):

In Linux,

```
ls -ld /proc
```

seems to give me what I need. The post above is odd.  `/proc/uptime` does not contain a date value – it would have to be subtracted from the current time. Maybe he meant:

```
date -d @$(( $(date +%s) - $(cut -f1 -d. /proc/uptime) ))
```

Comment: `uptime -s` provides a date value

Answer (score 1):

Under Bash, without pipes nor other processes; just text:

```
$ REPLY="$(</proc/uptime)"
$ REPLY="${REPLY%%.*}"
$ echo "$REPLY"
31207
```

(Just reused the `REPLY` default variable, but you can choose whatever you need)

Comment: Sure, Why not? Kinda clever use of variable substringiness. Cool. +1. Thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 0):

```
date -d @$(sed -n '/^btime /s///p' /proc/stat)
```

(yet another way to do this, which is useful in certain circumstances)

Answer (score 0):

Command:

```
(echo ' Currently:' | tr "\n" ' ' ; date +"%Y-%m-%d %k:%M:%S" ; echo '  Up Since:' | tr '\n' ' ' ; uptime -s ; echo '  Duration:' | tr '\n' ' ' ; uptime -p)
```

Output:

```
 Currently: 2016-05-09  9:06:29
  Up Since: 2016-05-04 12:56:04
  Duration: up 4 days, 20 hours, 10 minutes
```

Answer (score 0):

Clear and concise with [tuptime](https://github.com/rfrail3/tuptime/) command:

```
# tuptime -t
No.             Startup Date                                          Uptime            Shutdown Date   End                    Downtime

1     09:43:39 AM 08/08/2017      41 days, 0 hours, 51 minutes and 2 seconds   10:34:41 AM 09/18/2017    OK                  10 seconds
2     10:34:51 AM 09/18/2017                         1 minute and 16 seconds   10:36:07 AM 09/18/2017    OK                    1 second
3     10:36:08 AM 09/18/2017                       13 minutes and 20 seconds   10:49:28 AM 09/18/2017    OK                   3 seconds
4     10:49:31 AM 09/18/2017       45 days, 0 hours, 1 minute and 20 seconds   09:50:51 AM 11/02/2017    OK                   4 seconds
5     09:50:55 AM 11/02/2017                       27 minutes and 25 seconds   10:18:20 AM 11/02/2017    OK                   4 seconds
6     10:18:24 AM 11/02/2017                                       9 seconds   10:18:33 AM 11/02/2017    OK                   9 seconds
7     10:18:42 AM 11/02/2017      4 days, 5 hours, 41 minutes and 47 seconds   04:00:29 PM 11/06/2017    OK                  44 seconds
8     04:01:13 PM 11/06/2017    15 days, 17 hours, 33 minutes and 48 seconds   09:35:01 AM 11/22/2017   BAD   10 minutes and 40 seconds
9     09:45:41 AM 11/22/2017               8 hours, 9 minutes and 20 seconds   05:55:01 PM 11/22/2017   BAD     7 minutes and 8 seconds
10    06:02:09 PM 11/22/2017                1 hour, 7 minutes and 54 seconds   07:10:03 PM 11/22/2017   BAD   11 minutes and 30 seconds
11    07:21:33 PM 11/22/2017               1 hour, 58 minutes and 32 seconds   09:20:05 PM 11/22/2017    OK                   5 seconds
12    09:20:10 PM 11/22/2017                       14 minutes and 52 seconds   09:35:02 PM 11/22/2017   BAD    5 minutes and 52 seconds
13    09:40:54 PM 11/22/2017                         4 minutes and 6 seconds   09:45:00 PM 11/22/2017   BAD    4 minutes and 51 seconds
14    09:49:51 PM 11/22/2017             11 hours, 15 minutes and 10 seconds   09:05:01 AM 11/23/2017   BAD    7 minutes and 20 seconds
15    09:12:21 AM 11/23/2017      3 days, 2 hours, 17 minutes and 40 seconds   11:30:01 AM 11/26/2017   BAD   27 minutes and 44 seconds
16    11:57:45 AM 11/26/2017   109 days, 19 hours, 12 minutes and 37 seconds   07:10:22 AM 03/16/2018    OK                  17 seconds
17    07:10:39 AM 03/16/2018     25 days, 3 hours, 55 minutes and 59 seconds   12:06:38 PM 04/10/2018    OK                   3 seconds
18    12:06:41 PM 04/10/2018      8 days, 19 hours, 3 minutes and 20 seconds   07:10:01 AM 04/19/2018   BAD    3 minutes and 52 seconds
19    07:13:53 AM 04/19/2018     77 days, 9 hours, 44 minutes and 39 seconds
```

Comment: `tuptime` is not available by default.

Comment: It is available on the repository of the mayor Linux distributions. An `apt install tuptime`, `dnf install tuptime`, `apk add tuptime`, `pkg install tuptime`, etc... set up it on the system.

Answer (score 0):

On improving [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1429342), as that variant prints out inconsistent values for the second depending on when being executed due to truncating the value of `/proc/uptime`.

This variant does not truncate hence seems to provide a consistent value:

```
date -d "`cut -f1 -d' ' /proc/uptime` seconds ago" -u -Iseconds
```

Tested with `date (GNU coreutils) 9.1`. Consistency tested with: `` while date -d "`cut -f1 -d ' ' /proc/uptime` seconds ago" -u -Iseconds; do :; done | uniq ``

(This may would have been a comment, but I have not enough reputation here yet.)