# uptime -s changing reported time

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have a script that relies in time Ubuntu 18.04 is started found by:

```
uptime -s
```

I save that value in a file when I run the script. I noticed when I started Ubuntu that time was:

```
uptime -s
2019-01-07 18:01:59
```

After running for a bit more than two hours, same command reports now a different time (I remained logged in same account all this time):

```
uptime -s
2019-01-07 18:01:58
```

I would expect the command reports same time within same login session. But somehow time changes with 1 second (it is earlier now).

Is this an OS or tool issue?

```
https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/fs/proc/uptime.c
struct timespec64 uptime;
ktime_get_boottime_ts64(&uptime);
```

How can I get system up time without such fluctuation?

**Update:**

I though I found the answer in: [Linux: Getting date & time of system startup](https://superuser.com/questions/263486/linux-getting-date-time-of-system-startup)

But I was wrong, it just luck, after running a few more tests, one can see it is OS problem, the time rotates between 58 and 59 depending on nanoseconds:

```
$ date -d "`cut -f1 -d. /proc/uptime` seconds ago" +"%F %T.%N"
2019-01-07 18:01:58.670091767
$ date -d "`cut -f1 -d. /proc/uptime` seconds ago" +"%F %T.%N"
2019-01-07 18:01:58.627339874
$ date -d "`cut -f1 -d. /proc/uptime` seconds ago" +"%F %T.%N"
2019-01-07 18:01:58.708332394
$ date -d "`cut -f1 -d. /proc/uptime` seconds ago" +"%F %T.%N"
2019-01-07 18:01:58.821526069
$ date -d "`cut -f1 -d. /proc/uptime` seconds ago" +"%F %T.%N"
2019-01-07 18:01:58.604129974
$ date -d "`cut -f1 -d. /proc/uptime` seconds ago" +"%F %T.%N"
2019-01-07 18:01:58.469767199
$ date -d "`cut -f1 -d. /proc/uptime` seconds ago" +"%F %T.%N"
2019-01-07 18:01:59.264900963
$ date -d "`cut -f1 -d. /proc/uptime` seconds ago" +"%F %T.%N"
2019-01-07 18:01:58.986611962
$ date -d "`cut -f1 -d. /proc/uptime` seconds ago" +"%F %T.%N"
2019-01-07 18:01:58.851955874
$ date -d "`cut -f1 -d. /proc/uptime` seconds ago" +"%F %T.%N"
2019-01-07 18:01:58.958194732
$ date -d "`cut -f1 -d. /proc/uptime` seconds ago" +"%F %T.%N"
2019-01-07 18:01:59.066728481
```

I seems, there is no reliable system uptime to second level.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linux: Getting date & time of system startup](https://superuser.com/questions/263486/linux-getting-date-time-of-system-startup)

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer here:

[Linux: Getting date & time of system startup](https://superuser.com/questions/263486/linux-getting-date-time-of-system-startup)

This command seems to give correct result, unlike uptime -s

```
 date -d "`cut -f1 -d. /proc/uptime` seconds ago"
```

Example:

```
date -d "`cut -f1 -d. /proc/uptime` seconds ago"
Mo 7. Jan 18:01:59 CET 2019
```

It seems uptime -s is not reliable.